# passing javascript values as variables

Tags: javascript

Hello Great and amazing Stackoverflow Coders. 
I have initialized the following javascript below.

```
<script>


var first_name = localStorage.getItem("fname");
var last_name = localStorage.getItem("lname");

var age='21';

</script>
```

Now I wish to pass the javascript values above as variables

```
<script>
  $rootScope.user_fn = +first_name;
$rootScope.user_ln = +last_name;
$rootScope.user_age = +age;

</script>
```

The problem is that non of the values in the javascript above is passed and as such, 
it shows null values. but if I use `document.write()` function, it will print values but still will not pass the values
to javascript variables.

can some help me fix that thanks.

Comment: Why the `+` in front of the variable names? And are you trying to pass variables into an AngularJS controller or something like that?

Comment: they are already variables...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the "+" sign before a variable will convert that variable from string to number (will act as parseFloat/parseInt) and if the variable could not be converted - will result in NaN.

As I can see you have first and last name which probably are not numbers and when you try to convert them into numbers with +first_name, you get the "unexpected" null result

Comment: yes it results in NAN as you said. what is the right way to do it. thanks

Comment: Simply remove the '+' symbol... you only need the equals sign. That's how assignment works in Javascript (and most other popular programming languages).